# OData4j 0.7 Exception while retrieving workitems

Tags: java, odata4j

I am trying to retrieve workitems from TFS Server using OData4j  0.7 in Java.

Here is my code:

```
public List<TFSWorkItem> getWorkItems(final String projectName)  
{
    final List<TFSWorkItem> tfsWorkItems = new ArrayList<TFSWorkItem>();
    String filter = String.format("Project eq '%s'", projectName);
    Enumerable<OEntity> workItems = consumer.getEntities("WorkItems").filter(filter).execute();
    for (OEntity workitem : workItems)
    {
        System.out.println(workitem.getProperty("Title", String.class));
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal datetime format 2013-03-15T14:22:08.077+05:30
at org.odata4j.internal.InternalUtil.parseDateTimeFromXml(InternalUtil.java:96)
```

On further debugging the code I found that OData4j when trying to map the retrieved date from TFS server finds it incompatible .

Date retrieved from TFS :

```
2013-03-15T14:22:08.077+05:30
```

Date expected by OData4j :

```
2013-03-15T14:22:08.077
```

Is there a way where I can avoid this?

**Updated**

For anybody who is facing the same issue.

I have modified my code to :

```
    final String fields = "Id,Project,Title";
    Enumerable<OEntity> workItems = consumer.getEntities("WorkItems").filter(filter).select(fields.toString()).execute();
    for (OEntity workitem : workItems)
    {
        System.out.println("Id : " + workitem.getProperty("Id").getValue());
        System.out.println("Project : "+workitem.getProperty("Project").getValue());
        System.out.println("Title : "+workitem.getProperty("Title").getValue());
    }
```

Since I need only these fields to process I have given a select query to select "Id","Project" and "Title" instead of fetching all fields.
This is a temporary fix unless I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. Check out this post: [OData4J exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207354/odata4j-exceptions-odd-number-of-characters-and-bad-valuestring-part-of-key)

Basically, it boils down to setting the value of an `Edm.DateTime` column in C# code using `DateTime.Now`. The OData Producer should be using DateTime.**UtcNow**.

`DateTime.Now` includes local time zone information. Microsoft's code sees the local time zone info in the DateTime structure and sends back the `Edm.DataTime` field formatted as an `Edm.DateTimeOffset` string. The `DateTime.UtcNow` property does not include any time zone information, so it is correctly formatted as an `Edm.DateTim`e string when it is sent back to the OData Consumer.

I suspect this might be a bug in Microsoft's WCF Data Services stack or their Entity Framework.